# php 7.4 mysqli pointing to wrong path

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, php7

I recently updated to php 7.4 from php 7.3 on Debian and it seems apache is pointing mysqli to older path. How do I figure out from where it's causing issue?

Error -

```
[Mon Apr 06 07:22:13.384517 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17446] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to check if it's installed or not -

```
    php -m | grep mysqli
mysqli



php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20190902 => /usr/lib/php/20190902
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, myself. Had to disable apache php 7.3 module and enabled php 7.4. Sometimes, we forget to do basic step. Just sharing the answer so if anyone faces same issue, they can try below -

```
a2dismod php7.3
a2enmod php7.4
```